# Redraw direction paths in didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to redraw my direction path and move my marker to the current location. 
 I am currently doing this inside `didUpdateLocations` function but it gets glitchy because it draws multiple markers and path at the same time.

Here is my code:

```
let location = locations.last

let destination = CLLocation(latitude: order!.user_coord![0], longitude: order!.user_coord![1])

let origin = CLLocation(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

self.drawPath(startLocation: origin, endLocation: destination)

self.createMarker(titleMarker: order!.store_name!, iconMarker: UIImage(named: "icons8-user_filled")!, latitude: order!.user_coord![0], longitude: order!.user_coord![1])

self.createMarker(titleMarker: "User", iconMarker: UIImage(named: "icons8-mountain_biking")!, latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 17.0)
self.map.animate(to: camera)
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable

```
var drawFinished:Bool!
```

in viewDidLoad

```
drawFinished = false
```

in didUpdate

```
 if(!drawFinished)
 {   
   drawFinished = true

   let location = locations.last

   let destination = CLLocation(latitude: order!.user_coord![0], longitude: order!.user_coord![1])

   let origin = CLLocation(latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

   self.drawPath(startLocation: origin, endLocation: destination)

   self.createMarker(titleMarker: order!.store_name!, iconMarker:   UIImage(named: "icons8-user_filled")!, latitude: order!.user_coord![0], longitude: order!.user_coord![1])

   self.createMarker(titleMarker: "User", iconMarker: UIImage(named: "icons8-mountain_biking")!, latitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)

    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: (location?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (location?.coordinate.longitude)!, zoom: 17.0)

    self.map.animate(to: camera)

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

   }
```

when you want to update set

```
   drawFinished = false
```

and clear paths and annotations like this

```
   func clearMapOverlays()
  {
    for dl in self.myMapView.overlays
    {

        if(dl is  GMSPolyline )
        {

            self.myMapView.remove(dl)

        }


    }

     self.myMapView.setNeedsDisplay()

    for name  in self.myMapView.annotations
    {                        

           self.myMapView.removeAnnotation(anno)

    }


}
```

Comment: This will stop the marker and the direction path from updating i just tried it...so they'll not update as the location is updating

Comment: I can easily use mapView.clear() to clear the annotations and maps but it keeps clearing almost every second